# How to fix "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl" not found in native mode

Tags: apache-commons-logging, quarkus

When running a rest service in native mode I get a class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl not found exception. It's running fine with the openjdk mode.

I have write a small service rest to repoduce the problem.

The service Rest :

```java
package org.acme.rest.json;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory; 

import io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.substrate.ReflectiveClassBuildItem;
import io.quarkus.deployment.annotations.BuildStep;

@Path("/logs")
public class LogResource {
   private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LogResource.class);
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        log.info("jello");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When invoking this file I get

```java
xception handling request 04cf25a8-aafb-4b2a-978e-47a24009b22d-1 to /logs: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl (Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl)
```

Answer (score 5):

Following your advice, I got it running using the following config : 
pom.xml

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>native-image</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <enableHttpUrlHandler>true</enableHttpUrlHandler>
                 <additionalBuildArgs>-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/home/dev/repo/quarkus-mailbox-native//src/main/resources/reflectconfig.json,-H:DynamicProxyConfigurationFiles=/home/dev/repo/quarkus-mailbox-native/src/main/resources/dynamicproxy.json</additionalBuildArgs>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

reflect.json

```
[
    {
      "name" : "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl",
      "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
      "allPublicConstructors" : true,
      "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
      "allPublicMethods" : true,
      "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
      "allPublicClasses" : true
    },
    {
        "name" : "java.lang.String",
        "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
        "allPublicConstructors" : true,
        "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
        "allPublicMethods" : true,
        "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
        "allPublicClasses" : true
      },
      {
        "name" : "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory",
        "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
        "allPublicConstructors" : true,
        "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
        "allPublicMethods" : true,
        "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
        "allPublicClasses" : true
      },
      {
        "name" : "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog",
        "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
        "allPublicConstructors" : true,
        "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
        "allPublicMethods" : true,
        "allDeclaredClasses" : true,
        "allPublicClasses" : true
      }
]
```

Thanks for your help.

X.

Answer (score 3):

Please use JBoss Logging instead of Commons Logging:

```java
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LogResource.class.getName());
```

with `Logger` being `org.jboss.logging.Logger`.

JBoss Logging setup is fully taken care of by Quarkus.

If you want to use another logging facility, you will need to do the setup yourself. In your case, you would need to register `LogFactoryImpl` for reflection to make it work with GraalVM.

If you really don't want to use JBoss Logging (whih is a bad idea in my opinion as it has all the features you need), you have to follow the instructions of the GraalVM documentation: https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/Reflection.md#manual-configuration .

I recommend using the `@AutomaticFeature` as you just need to add a class in your application.

If you go the JSON config way, you can provide some additional arguments via `<additionalBuildArgs>` in the configuration of the Maven native-image phase.

Comment: I tried to register the LogFactoryImpl but I 'm did not find a way to do it.  Can you show me some example ?

Comment: I updated my answer to give more instructions about the registration.

Comment: the link is dead, now the documentation can be found at https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Reflection/#manual-configuration

Comment: If you are using libraries that have dependencies on other logging libraries such as Apache Commons Logging, Log4j or Slf4j, you can exclude them from the dependencies and use one of the adapters provided by JBoss Logging.
https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-adapters