# Quarkus native build UnresolvedElementException exception

Tags: native, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

On running the following command, I'm getting the UnresolvedElementException

```
mvn package -e -Dquarkus.native.remote-container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.native-image-xmx=12000m -Dnative
```

My code is as follows

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProfileStateLookupDao implements PanacheRepository<ProfileStateLookupEntity> {

    Map<Pair<String,String>, Long> profileStateLookupMap;

    public void initMap() {
        profileStateLookupMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<ProfileStateLookupEntity> requesterIdLookupEntities = findAll().list();
        requesterIdLookupEntities.forEach(x -> profileStateLookupMap
                .put(new MutablePair<>(x.getDeliveryStatus(), x.getState()), x.getStateId()));
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair. This error is reported at image build time because class com.thales.odc.consumeranalytics.dao.ProfileStateLookupDao is registered for linking at image build time by command line                           
at parsing com.thales.odc.consumeranalytics.dao.ProfileStateLookupDao.findStateIdByDeliveryStatusAndProfileState(ProfileStateLookupDao.java:39)
```

Comment: have you try reflect json for apache commons https://stackoverflow.com/a/56947164/175554